# Having trouble creating a Python Singly Linked List

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list

First of all, I am coming from a background in C/C++/Java. I have decided to learn Python to expand my skills and hopefully delve into some Web Development. I have only been learning it for about two days, and I have been trying to create some simple Data Structures.

I am getting so many errors, and I can't figure out what to do! I have tried to research it, and I still can't figure it out. I'm getting errors about the number of positional arguments passed to my LinkedList member functions, and when I take those out, it says that self is not defined in my Node function definitions.

```
class Node:

    def __init__():
        self.data = None
        self.nextNode = None  

    def set_and_return_Next():
        self.nextNode = Node()
        return self.nextNode

    def getNext():
        return self.nextNode

    def getData():
        return self.data

    def setData(d):
        self.data = d


class LinkedList:

    def buildList(array):
        head = Node()
        head.setData(array[0])
        temp = head
        for i in array:
            temp = temp.set_and_return_Next()
            temp.setData(array[i])
            tail = temp
        return self.head

    def printList():
        tempNode = head
        while(tempNode!=tail):
            print(tempNode.getData())
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext()

myArray = [3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 21]

myList = LinkedList()
myList.buildList(myArray)
myList.printList()
```

I know they are probably stupid mistakes, but please help.

Comment: as an aside it is rare to have an actual need to create something like this in python ... if its just practice coding python thats fine, but if your planning to reuse this in programs there are better builtin datatypes to use

Comment: after you've done that, you should change `for i in array:`in the `buildlist` definition to `for i in range(len(array)):` **Edit:** On second thoughts, it would also help if you said something more about this simple example that you have provided because there are so many errors (!) that it's difficult to suggest anything (besides the obvious syntactical stuff) without knowing the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP wrote:

> Fixed it! Here is the new code:
>
> ```
> #Matthew's Simple Python
> # Practice Linked List
> class Node:
>
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.data = None
>         self.nextNode = None  
>
>     def set_and_return_Next(self):
>         self.nextNode = Node()
>         return self.nextNode
>
>     def getNext(self):
>         return self.nextNode
>
>     def getData(self):
>         return self.data
>
>     def setData(self, d):
>         self.data = d
>
> class LinkedList:
>
>     def buildList(self, array):
>         self.head = Node()
>         self.head.setData(array[0])
>         self.temp = self.head
>         for i in array[1:]:
>             self.temp = self.temp.set_and_return_Next()
>             self.temp.setData(i)
>             self.tail = self.temp
>         return self.head
>
>     def printList(self):
>         tempNode = self.head
>         while(tempNode!=self.tail):
>             print(tempNode.getData())
>             tempNode = tempNode.getNext()
>         print(self.tail.getData())
>
> myArray = [3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 21]
>
> myList = LinkedList()
> myList.buildList(myArray)
> myList.printList()
> ```
>
> Here is the output:

```
>>> 
3
5
4
6
2
6
7
8
9
10
21
```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)

Answer (score 5):

In Python (unlike C++), every instance method has an implicit first argument: the instance of the class. It's called `self`, by convention:

```
def some_method(self, arg1, ...):
```

Also, in Python, you use lists in place of arrays just about everywhere. What you called `myArray` is actually a list. Iterating through lists and other iterables iterates over the *elements*, not the indices:

```
for element in your_list:
    do_something(element)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that about the iterations, obviously that was a huge mistake. Very different than anything I've seen before. It's also different because in C++/Java, the **this** keyword isn't always required. Anyway I fixed it.